# Problems with setting the background of the whole website with a DropDownList

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

So here's the deal, I've got this DropDownList on my Login.aspx page, using that DropDown I'd like to set the background for the whole website. Having a MasterPage I just thought I should set the color of the body.

Here's my html for the `<asp:DropDownList>`:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblColor" ClientIDMode="Static" AssociatedControlID="ddlColor" class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></asp:Label>
        <%--Update Panel за цветовете--%>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updateColor" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlColor" style="width:100%" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged" aria-describedby="lbColor" data-taggle="dropdown" data-style="DropDownListHint-datastyle" class="btn dropdown-toggle DropDownListHint-datastyle">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Бял" Value="White" Selected="True" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Зелен" Value="Green" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's 2 problem I'm experiencing.
1st one being that when I set the color of the body, after clicking on the Login button the color gets removed on the next page.
2nd one being that I can't get the page not to flash even when using an update panel.

Here's my C# code-behind.

```
protected void ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var body = Master.FindControl("bodyMasterPage") as HtmlGenericControl;

    if (ddlColor.SelectedValue == "Green")
    {
        body.Style.Add("background-color", "#D2F6E2!important");
    }
    else if (ddlColor.SelectedValue == "White")
    {
        body.Style.Add("background-color", "#ccc!important");
    }
    updateColor.Update();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: Use Themes and Skins https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx

Comment: Is the background color supposed to persist to the user's next session, or just during the current session?

Comment: Just the current session.

Comment: You don't really need to use a WebForms control, then. A plain select element or (since it looks like you're using Bootstrap in some fashion) a dropdown would work, with some JavaScript. If that works for you, I could bang out a simplified example.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. But is using the WebForms control a negative in any way?

Comment: Eh, that's a bit of a loaded question. In this case, it's not necessary, since you don't really want a postback, nor do you really need all the server-processing associated with generating the eventual select element.

Comment: Sounds good, I really didn't think of doing it with js since I'm a bit more confortable with C# myself. Thanks for the answer, is there a simplified version of this I can look at since I can't seem to find it ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to keep this as simple as possible. I would expect you to build off of the example below.

First, let's just build a simple `<select>`, like so:

```
<select id="ddlColor" class="form-control">
    <option value="#d2f6e2">Бял</option>
    <option value="#ccc">Зелен</option>
</select>
```

I've pulled the values from your code-behind, and we'll see why in a moment.

Second, let's build a jQuery event handler for when the select's value changes:

```
$('#ddlColor').on('change', function(e){


});
```

I'm assuming jQuery is available since I see Bootstrap CSS classes in your markup, which normally means you're also using `bootstrap.js` somewhere, which has jQuery as a dependency.

Third, we grab the select's selected **value**, and use the jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function to apply your style to the body element:

```
$('#ddlColor').on('change', function(e){
    var color = $(this).val();

    $('body').css('background-color', color);
});
```

This goes anywhere in your page that you either already have scripts or you can add a script tag, as long as the script is after you've loaded jQuery.

As a note, the CSS function doesn't seem to like those `!important` modifiers, so I removed them. If you absolutely need them, I'd think about creating some classes for these colors instead, and use the [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) functions instead.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hfrjufto/

And a version that persists the value in localStorage: https://jsfiddle.net/hfrjufto/3/

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('bgcolor')) {
  populateStorage();
} else {
  setStyles();
}

function setStyles() {
  var color = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');

  $('body').css('background-color', color);
}

function populateStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', $('#ddlColor').val());

  setStyles();
}

$('#ddlColor').on('change', function(e) {
  populateStorage();
});
```

Comment: Thank you its really easy to read like this.
Should I add the .on('change' to my document ready or no?

Comment: @AlexanderHristov Yeah, if you already have a document ready somewhere, that's a good place to add this.

Comment: And, if you wanted this to persist longer, you could always store the value in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) - that takes some thought, though, so read that reference if it sounds like something you want to do.

Comment: It works, but the problem with it being only on the Login.aspx page persists. Any ideas on what could be causing it?

Comment: @AlexanderHristov Well, this isn't writing anything into the HTML of the page, so each new page request will reset the value. That's where a cookie or localStorage comes into play. The MDN actually has an example that is somewhat close to what you're trying to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: @AlexanderHristov I added an example that builds off of the example from the MDN. Let me know how that works.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, I'll try the LocalStorage method now.

Comment: Should the whole jsfiddle example code go into the document.ready or should it be outside, since when I did a debugger it went through the code once, saved the color which is selected "Бял" and didn't go through again when changing to "Зелен".

Comment: I would expect the former. The if/else statement should only be executed on page load (which updates the background color to match what's stored). After that, the functions would only be called when the select changes. Do note that the last example does have a change to the event handler.

Comment: If you're still using an ASP.NET control, make sure that the `AutoPostback` value is set to false, otherwise you're posting before localstorage can be set.

Comment: I've changed to the <select> control, after going back and forth I realized that going to another page and comming back to the Login.aspx one the color is saved. For example going to Empty.aspx will change the color to "Бял", but going back to Login.aspx it will be saved to "Зелен".

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain? That includes subdomain. If so, the value _should_ be persisting correctly.

Comment: They're on the same domain and using the same masterpage.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what to tell you. I'd have to build a simple ASP.NET project to test what might be going on, and I'm not going to do that at the moment. If you're using your back button to go back and forth, maybe try refreshing the page and see if the value is actually being changed in storage. You might just be looking at a cached version of the page.

Comment: I'm using a "Logout" button, I even tried rebuilding the website which loaded the page with the value selected in the previous build. But it was only for the Login.aspx page.

Comment: The only thought that comes to mind is whether you're going from http to https when logging in and out. If so, those are considered different domains by the browser, so those would be two different localstorage instances.

Comment: Both pages are http and not https.

Comment: Wait, should I be writing the actual jquery in the Login.aspx or the MasterPage?

Comment: Master page, if you want the values applied to each page.

Comment: Moving the jquery to MasterPage did it, thank you so much for being extremely patient with me. I'm sorry if my dumb mistake lost your time.

Comment: No problemo. Glad you figured it out.